# Checkbox not clickable with javascript. .click() is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, checkbox, automation, getelementsbyclassname

I've tried automating a checkbox to click with JavaScript, in Google Chrome.

This is what the inspector of the browser shows me when I inspect the checkbox:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="lucide lucide-square" data-icon="Square" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"><rect x="3" y="3" width="18" height="18" rx="2" ry="2"></rect></svg>
```

This is how I've tried to click the button:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('lucide lucide-square')[0].click();
```

It does recognise the element but it doesn't click it.

It returns the error:

```
VM3971:1 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0].click is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:60
```

Anybody can help with this, please?

I've tried also `.onclick` or also to call the element with querySelector, but it doesn't work.

I was expecting the checkbox to work like other ones on the same website, which were all clickable with `.click()`

Comment: A checkbox should be an input element. This is an SVG image.

Comment: Also `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a **list** of elements. The list may be empty (`length` = 0) but it is still a list. You have to operate on each element of the list individually for stuff like setting up event handlers.

Comment: @dram95 : An image can be used to replace a checkbox... And when the user clicks it, the event bubbles up to the "real" not visible control. -- That is all assumption tought.

Comment: In other words, it's most probably a parent of that svg that handles the click.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Is there a way to track that?
I've tried searching for 'button' and 'checkbox' but couldn't find any class or id related to that.

Comment: try `document.getElementsByClassName('lucide lucide-square')[0].parentElement.click()`... and `document.getElementsByClassName('lucide lucide-square')[0].parentElement.parentElement.click()`... and so on.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm posting the [answer of @LouysPatriceBessette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76398187/checkbox-not-clickable-with-javascript-click-is-not-a-function/76398372#comment134716687_76398187), which worked for me

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('lucide lucide-square')[0].parentElement.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The element you're trying to click isn't actually a button, it's an [`<svg>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg) element that looks like a button but is really more like an image. Only real buttons have the `.click()` method, however you can artificially fire the `click` event by creating a new event with [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) and sending it to the button:

```js
const btn = document.getElementsByClassName('lucide lucide-square')[0];

// example event handler
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('clicked');
});

var event = new CustomEvent('click');
btn.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="lucide lucide-square" data-icon="Square" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"><rect x="3" y="3" width="18" height="18" rx="2" ry="2"></rect></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, MIchael. I've tried but without success. I only get the 'clicked' message and 'true' from the console.